# Showing a Div with background-color only

Tags: html, css

Following is my HTML code,

```
 <body>
 <div id="wrapper">
 <div id="left_border"></div>
 <div id="main_content">
 some text </br>
 some text </br>
 some text </br>
 some text </br>
 </div>
 <div id="right_border"></div>
 </div>
 </body>
```

Here is my css,

```
  #wrapper {
  margin: 25px 20px;
  height: auto;
  }

  #left_border, #right_border {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  }

  #left_border {
  float: left;
  }

  #right_border {
  float: right;
  }
```

my problem is, i am unable to showcase my border divs. I need to show both the borders up to my length of main_content div. Any idea?

Comment: Why not you define **border-right** & **border-left** on your main_content DIV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/6ZGXd/3/ The border will be the same height as the content div.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use `border` css property. For example:

```
div#main_content {
    border-left: 20px solid #ff0000;
    border-right: 20px solid #ff0000;
}
```

And no fake `div` for borders.

Answer (score 0):

Set height in `#left_border, #right_border`

```
#left_border, #right_border {
display: block;
width: 20px;
height: 80px;
background-color: red;
}
```

and this code
    #main_content{
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    }

[Demo Link:](http://jsfiddle.net/RB46S/1/)

Comment: My border has to set its height according to the content in #main_content. i tried giving height: auto to the border divs but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

psur is right if you really are trying to create a border, but if your purpose is to create content to the left and right, then move the two border  inside the main_content and give them a height of 100%.  There are still some margin issues, but that gets you on the way...

Answer (score 0):

In order for your backgrounds to show, you need some content in the div.  Add &nbsp; between the left and right border opening & closing divs

hth

Answer (score -1):

Actually you made a bit of wrong markup you should write the markup like this :-

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
     <div id="main_content">
     some text </br>
     some text </br>
     some text </br>
     some text </br> some text </br> some text </br> some text </br> some text </br> some text </br>    some text </br>
     </div>
     </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
  margin: 25px 20px;
  }

#main_content {
  border-right:2px solid red;
  border-left:2px solid red;
}
```

http://tinkerbin.com/IwKyVILk

Comment: Links are a good supplement to an answer, but shouldn't be an essential part of the answer. There is a lot of markup there, what have you changed? Answers should not be a game of spot-the-difference. The markup you link to has validity errors in it.

Comment: @Quentin did u check my demo ?

Comment: I think @Quentin you don't see the answers properly and you just down vote it...... right ? if its not than reply ..........

Comment: @ShailenderArora yup this is the right markup it should like this as mentioned...........